# How to convert bit varying to numeric in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, binary, decimal

I am trying to convert `bit varying`to `numeric` (decimal value) in postgresql

```
select cast('10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010000000101'::bit varying as numeric);
```

I have tried the `cast` function but getting below error.

> ERROR:  cannot cast type bit varying to numeric LINE 1: select
>   cast('10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010...
>                  ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: cannot cast type bit varying to numeric SQL state: 42846
>   Character: 8

Output should be : `5429503678976`. Any suggestions

**EDIT:** I do not know the max value so can not use

```
select b'10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010000000101'::bigint
```

Thanks

Comment: `select b'10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010000000101'::bigint` seems to work

Comment: @SalmanA untill the number does not fit annymore in a `bigint`, well to be fair the topicstarter didn't say how large/high numbers it should support so your comment could be a possible answer?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, as also mentioned by @Raymon Nijlaland I do not the max value and dealing with the `numeric` in the application.

Comment: @KubaDo SQL Server (MSSQL)/TSQL is not the same as PostgreSQL.. Also the SQL tag on this website indicates ANSI/ISO SQL standard valid SQL code and not SQL Server (MSSQL) .. In short that information what you linked is pretty unuseable in PostgreSQL,

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank You for explanation, i have deleted comment. Still learnin, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could break it up into individual bits, convert those to the appropriate numeric values and then sum them together:

```
with data(d) as (VALUES (B'10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010000000101') )
select sum(parts) FROM (
  SELECT get_bit(d, length(d) - n)::numeric * pow(2::numeric, n-1) as parts
  from data, generate_series(1, length(d), 1) g(n)
) sub
;
                sum
------------------------------------
 51185893014090757.0000000000000000
(1 row)
```

Note that this gives me the same answer as `select b'10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010000000101'::bigint;` but it should work for larger values as well, where bigint would be out of range.

You could turn it into a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitstring_to_numeric(l_bit_string varbit) 
RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT sum(parts) FROM (
    SELECT get_bit(l_bit_string, 
                   length(l_bit_string) - n)::numeric * pow(2::numeric, n-1) as parts
    from generate_series(1, length(l_bit_string), 1) g(n)
    ) sub
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;

select bitstring_to_numeric(B'10110101110110010100110001101010100111011011010000000101');
        bitstring_to_numeric
------------------------------------
 51185893014090757.0000000000000000
```